# Maximum entropy distribution given constrained minimum, maximum, and mean

Tags: probability, entropy

What kind of distribution do we get if we constrain the range to be the unit interval and also constrain the mean to be $\alpha$?

---

If we read [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Other_examples), we see the following two examples of maximum entropy distributions.

The standard normal distribution is the maximum entropy distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

Similarly, if we restrict out attention to distributions with bounded support, then the uniform distribution is the maximum entropy distribution.

I'm writing a small library to estimate quantiles in a stream of data and am currently keeping track of the sample minimum, maximum, and mean, but am not using the sample mean to estimate quantiles directly.

So, *what kind of distribution do we get if we constrain the range to be the unit interval and also constrain the mean to be $\alpha$*?

In general, is there a good strategy for figuring out a closed form for the pdf of a maximum entropy distribution satisfying an arbitrary collection of properties?

Comment: For each $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, let $c$ solve the equation $\alpha = 1 - \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{e^c - 1}$. (Such $c$ uniquely exists.) Then the distribution with the following p.d.f. $$ f_{\alpha}(x) = \frac{c}{e^c - 1} e^{cx} \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x) $$ maximizes the entropy over the space of continuous distributions supported on $[0, 1]$ and has mean $\alpha$. This follows from variational argument.

Comment: @SangchulLee, there must be something I'm missing ... but I think that $f_{0.5}$ should be just the uniform distribution since the mean constraint is redundant in the case. $f_{\alpha}$ does not appear to be a constant times an indicator function when $\alpha = 0.5$ .

Comment: That's a good point. As $\alpha \to \frac{1}{2}$, we can prove that $c \to 0$. In such case, $\frac{c}{e^c - 1} \to 1$, so this indeed reduces to the uniform distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee, want to write that as an answer, so we can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $\mathcal{A}$ denote the set of all $f \in L^1([0,1])$ with the constraints

$$f \geq 0, \qquad \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1, \qquad \int_{0}^{1} x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \alpha. \tag{*} $$

We claim that the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) $h(\cdot)$ is maximized over $\mathcal{A}$ by

$$f_{\max}(x) = e^{ax+b} \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$$

for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. (Note that such $a$ and $b$ are uniquely determined from $\text{(*)}$.) Indeed, for any $f \in \mathcal{A}$, the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) $D(f||f_{\max})$ is non-negative, and so, we get

$$ 0 \leq D(f||f_{\max}) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \log \left(\frac{f(x)}{e^{ax+b}}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x = -h(f) - (a\alpha + b). $$

On the other hand, by a direct computation we get $h(f_{\max}) = -(a\alpha + b)$. So it follows that

$$ h(f) \leq h(f_{\max}) $$

for all $f \in \mathcal{A}$. This proves that $f_{\max}$ is a maximizer of $h(\cdot)$ over $\mathcal{A}$. (Together with the fact that $h(\cdot)$ is strictly concave, it is easy to prove that $f_{\max}$ is the *unique* maximizer up to modification on null sets.)

---

For the reference, see Theorem 5.1 of Keith Conrad. [Probability Distributions and Maximum Entropy.](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/entropypost.pdf)